# PHP - Switch case & _GET and Dynamic URL creation

Tags: php, function, switch-statement, dynamic-url

**What I have in my index page:**

```
    if(isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d']!="" ){
        switch ($_GET['d']) {
            case 'singlerequests':
            ViewSingleRequests();
            break;

    }
```

I have a sidebar menu in which I call cases like `index.php?d=singlerequests`, this saves me from creating a new php file every link i want to have in the file.

**What I want to do:**
I created a page, in which I am listing multiple rows of date.  My data row has multiple columns so instead of showing all data with all columns on that page, I will only have a summary table and a "View More" link next to each row, in which they view the full data on another page. (something like below)

```
Row Name | View More Link
Row Name | View More Link
Row Name | View More Link
```

I can retrieve the unique ID for that row in my code but i dont know how I can pass that data(identifier) through above switch case to another function, where i will display all columns of that row to user? If it's not possible that way, how can i do it in a different way?

Thanks.

Comment: What about adding another parameter to the link and thus to the $_GET, like `index.php?d=singlerequests&id=1` and `ViewSingleRequests($_GET['id']);` Don't forget to check and sanitize input!

Comment: Thank you ZorgoZ, that worked! I will work on sanitizing the input.